# How to interpret statistics Z3

Tags: z3, smt

I get the following statistics in Z3.

```
(:added-eqs            24529
 :binary-propagations  43837
 :bv-bit2core          7115
 :bv-conflicts         156
 :bv-diseqs            10395
 :bv-dynamic-diseqs    10028
 :bv->core-eq          10401
 :conflicts            409
 :decisions            4840
 :del-clause           84926
 :final-checks         2
 :max-generation       4
 :memory               5.69
 :minimized-lits       467
 :mk-clause            88358
 :propagations         90195
 :quant-instantiations 3388
 :restarts             3
 :time                 0.83)
```

I'd like to know what the metrics used for each result row.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have the feeling that interpreting the statistics the right way is quite an art, and that the Z3 developers are probably the only ones who really know how to do that. Anyway, here is what I know ... or believe:

`quant-instantiations` indicates the number of instantiated quantifiers. The fewer instantiations the better, but you of course don't want to make your patterns/triggers too strict because Z3 then won't be able to prove anything.

`conflicts` indicate assignments that happen in the theory subsolvers and that did not make the formula true. If the formula can be satisfied and the number of conflicts is high, it basically means that the prover tried lots of assignments that did not satisfy the formula, i.e., that the prover did not manage to explore the search space in the direction of the goal.

Related questions:

- [Z3 statistics: what does time measure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340888/z3-statistics-what-does-time-measure)
- [Z3 real arithmetic and statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949633/z3-real-arithmetic-and-statistics)
- [Which statistics indicate an efficient run of Z3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841193/which-statistics-indicate-an-efficient-run-of-z3)

Comment: Does the time mean real time or CPU time?

Comment: @DingbaoXie I don't know, sorry. You could try to find out by checking a complicated formula that takes quite a while to be checked and by giving the Z3 task/process a very low priority. That way it should become apparent which time is measured.

Comment: I dream of a script: it takes a set of benchmarks and tunes Z3 for them. And also says where most of the time goes to. And also hints if the encoding is not efficient! :)

Comment: @Ayrat Sounds awesome. Please don't hesitate to contact me once your dream has come true :-)

Comment: time is expressed in seconds?

Comment: @Robert Yes, in seconds.

Comment: Memory expressed with that metric? Memory represents the memory consumption by z3?

Comment: @Robert I don't know, sorry. The Z3 developers surely do. Should you find out, please post it here.